# List item li hover style not working on a page

Tags: html, css

on this web page http://nkarch.lifeintheuktest.co/the-work.aspx I have `<li>` elements inside the `div` with `id=ProjectsGrid`.

The css rule `#ProjectsGrid ul li a:hover h4` is working fine in chrome and IE but not working on firefox.

Any ideas?

Comment: could you please post related HTML and CSS codes? And preferably put your minimal example that reproduces your problem on jsfiddle to demonstrate your problem - this can help you get answer quick.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `font-weight`. You don't have it when not hovered. Set:

```
.TopNavigation a:link {
    color: white;
    line-height: 200%;
    text-decoration: none;

    font-weight: 800;
}
```

and it will be fine.

Edit: Add `font-weight` on every `<div>` you haven't, because I see it's not only the nav problematic.

Comment: Sorry the issue is with #ProjectsGrid not with TopNavigation

Comment: To be specific the background color of the h4 is not changing on hover to red